# solaris echo " [ " character problem

Tags: bash

i have bash script such as

---

```
for i in `echo a [ matched.lines`
do
echo $i
done
```

why output of this script below

> a
>
> [
>
> matched.lines

---

i want output text as it is

> a [ matched.lines

---

how can i do that

thanks for help

Comment: Why are you using the outer loop instead of a single command? `echo a [ matched.lines`

Comment: no this is just demo purposes here, i have file to read with several lines which includes " [ " so code has loop

Comment: The square bracket is not the problem here. Describe more of what you really want to do. Provide a better, more complete example.

Answer (score 2):

The script echos each token seperately. Use `echo -n $i` inside `do ... done`.

Comment: but this time there is no new line on output :(

Comment: just append a trailing `echo' to the program.

Comment: what do you mean with trailing echo ?

Answer (score 0):

i have replaced ' ' characters to '' with sed global replace and there is no new line on output of script thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

to read a file using shell, use while read loop

```
while read -r loop
do
 case "$line" in 
  *]* ) echo $line;;
 esac
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that's not going to do what you want it to. Your `for` loop is using a space as a delimiter to it's arguments. This will cause each one of the item's to echo on a seperate line. Adding a -n doesn't work here because you will not get the \n at the end of the line. Honestly I don't see what it is your trying to do here. If you just want to echo this "a [ matched.lines" as a string you can do this:

```
for i in "a [ matched.lines";do
  echo $i
done
```

But I feel you're going to misunderstand how to use a for loop....